# Highest memory transfer

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

Let's say that a jump instruction is located at memory address  0x20CE88C0. What is the highest (i.e., greatest) 32-bit memory address to which this jump can transfer control?
I know the highest address can be 2^26, but I see others saying 2^28. I don't understand the difference. Why is 2^28?

Comment: The highest J instruction operand *value* is 2^26 (because that's all the bits that are left). That value is not the next PC, though.

Answer (score 1):

The J-Type instruction is very simple:

```
opcode  target
   6      26              // field size, as bit count
```

---

```
target := instruction[25:0]
JumpAddr := { PC+4[31:28], target, 2'b0 }
PC := JumpAddr
```

This is the description in the [MIPS Green Sheet / Quick Reference](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf) Data.  Though a somewhat funny notation (some kind of [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register-transfer_level)), it tells us what we need to know about the possible range of jump instructions, by telling us how the processor decodes the J-Type instructions.

What this says is that the current PC+4 provides the upper 4 bits of the new PC address.  Then the address field, sometimes called `immediate` otherwise called `target` — either way is 26 bits wide — provides the next 26 bits, and then 00 are the next 2 bits, for a total of 32 bit value for the next PC.

So, with that information, you can compute or form the largest possible address that can be reached from the given `PC`.  Take `PC+4`'s top 4 bits, and then (string/concatenate onto those 4 bits) a 26 bit max value — its 26 bits unsigned, so 26 all 1's is the max value — then concatenate a 00 (two zero bits) and to make the 32-bit value of the exact address of the maximum addressable location from the `j`/`jal` starting at the given `PC`.

Comment: i.e. `j` instructions are region-absolute: you can jump to any address within the same 2^28-byte (256MiB) region as the branch-delay slot after the `j`.